# R - Unique values from days under x days from given observation dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to get an ordered vector of all values from the *text* column that are from the current *date* not further than 15 days (both back and forward). Example dataset looks like this:

```r
Data <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-15", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-18", "2020-03-01"), 
             text = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

As you can see, every row has a *date* and a *text*. What I want ot do is for every row, subset every row that which is not further than 15 days from the current row, take all values of *text*, on this vector, use unique() and then sort it alphabetically (so that "A C" and "C A" are both made into "A C"). It does not matter how many rows are in between 2 values as long as they are inside of the 15 days window. Therefore, I am looking for a separate answer for every row.

Example: For row 1, it has itself (text "A") and row 2 (text "B") inside of the 15 days window (row 2 is 14 days away). Therefore, the answer will be "A B". For row 2, the same answer will be used, as the only row within the 15 days window is row 1 (row 3 is 17 days away).

The answer should be usable in dplyr pipe, if possible. The results should then look like this:

```r
Data %>%
  mutate(result = c("A B", "A B", "A C", "A C", "A C D", "C D"))
```

I have thought about using filter(), but I am not sure how to do a subset for every observation separately.

Comment: Can you please explain more/ You say "not further than 15 days". The difference between "A" and "C" is 31 days - why is it included in the result?

Comment: Tried to explain myself more in the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `runner` and `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)
Data <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-15", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-18", "2020-03-01"), 
                   text = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))


library(runner)
Data %>% 
  mutate(result = map2_chr(runner(x = text,
                              idx = date,
                              lag = -15,
                              k = '16 days',
                              f = list), 
                       runner(x = text,
                              idx = date,
                              lag = 0,
                              k = '16 days',
                              f = list),
                       ~paste(sort(union(.x, .y)), collapse = ' ')))
#>         date text result
#> 1 2020-01-01    A    A B
#> 2 2020-01-15    B    A B
#> 3 2020-02-01    C    A C
#> 4 2020-02-03    A    A C
#> 5 2020-02-18    C  A C D
#> 6 2020-03-01    D    C D
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This works well and fast even on my huge dataset, thank you!

One thing: It shows me the result in the form of c("TEXT1", "TEXT2"), can I get rid of this somehow? Maybe inset paste with a separator somewhere?

Comment: @JirkaČep, Glad to have been of help. Please feel free to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach with `map` from `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

Data %>%
  mutate(Roll_text = map(
    date, 
    ~paste(sort(unique(text[date >= (.x - days(15)) & date <= (.x + days(15))])), collapse = " ")
  ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it on the head of my data and it worked well, but for the whole thing it was unforatunately super slow. I appreciate the help though!